# Time/Date conversion from numeric

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, datetime-format, date-formatting

I have recently come across a time series dataset (in R) that had a numeric time index in the following format:

1.586183e+12 1.586184e+12 1.586185e+12 1.586186e+12 1.586187e+12 1.586188e+12

The data should be in 15 minute intervals. I have tried some of a usual conversions, such as as.POSIXct(), but that doesn't seem to work. I was hoping that someone could point me to the right format conversion.

Many thanks

Comment: Did you try to provide an origin and timezone? 

See help page of `as.POSIXct`

Comment: It looks like the information is the number of milliseconds from the beginning of time.  Divide by 1000 and then pass to as.POSIXct like this: `as.POSIXct(1.586183e+12/1000, origin="1970-01-01")`

Comment: This is unclear to me, what do you mean by "The data should be in 15 minute intervals"? Please state expected output.

Answer (score 0):

// Sample numeric time index

```
// Sample numeric time index
```

numeric_time_index <- c(1.586183e+12, 1.586184e+12, 1.586185e+12, 1.586186e+12, 1.586187e+12, 1.586188e+12)

// Convert milliseconds to seconds
time_seconds <- numeric_time_index / 1000

// Convert to POSIXct
time_posix <- as.POSIXct(time_seconds, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")

// Print the result
print(time_posix)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).